# I got error forbidden when I using cloud functions and express routing

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, url-routing, google-cloud-functions

I using Firebase Hosting for building REST API and I have a problem with a URL routing.

This is an example which works fine:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; 
import * as express from 'express';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const app = express();

//  /user
export const user = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log("app", app)
    return res.send({
        name: "Leon",
        age: 23
    })
});
```

/user response:
{
name: "Leon",
age: 23
}

This is an example where I use express for dynamic URL routing:
[Example resource](http://abe.ghost.io/advaned-url-routing-in-google-cloud-functions-for-firebase/)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; 
import * as express from 'express';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    res.send('Root page');
});

app.get('/second', (req, res) => {  
    res.send('Sub function');
});

app.get('/hello/:name', (req, res) => {  
    res.send(`Hello ${req.params.name}`);
});

exports.route = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

/ response => Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.

/second response => Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /second from this server.

/hello/johndoe response => Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /hello/johndoe from this server.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Express middleware is cors.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; 
import * as express from 'express';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

app.use(cors);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    res.send('Root page');
});

app.get('/second', (req, res) => {  
    res.send('Sub function');
});

app.get('/hello/:name', (req, res) => {  
    res.send(`Hello ${req.params.name}`);
});

exports.route = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be solved at your GCP Console. Just follow these steps:

1. Go to your [GCP Console](https://cloud.google.com/) and login
2. On the top menu, select the corresponding Firebase project
3. On the left menu go to Cloud Functions
4. Click the checkbox of your function (not the name of the function)
5. Once selected, on the right menu select "Add member"
6. On "New member" type allUsers
7. On the Select function bar, select Cloud Functions -> Cloud functions invoker
8. Click on "Save" and then "Allow public access" on the pop-up warning
   And you're good to go!